# Which (PHP?) framework to use for a SOAP frontend with AJAX

Tags: php, web-applications, soap

I'm planning to develop a web application. All the heavy logic will be done via SOAP webservices; this question is about the frontend which will thus have to communicate with the backend via SOAP. It should be easy to use, make using SOAP services easy, and integrate AJAX functionality in a nice way. I was thinking something in PHP, but am basically open to other suggestions.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to consider Codeigniter for a PHP framework.  It's easy to use, quick, and offers many other pluses.  For my application, I ended up using Codeigniter combined with Scriptaculous for AJAX.  I think it'd be difficult to find a framework that is great at doing everything.

If REST is an option, here's what looks to be a great tutorial for Codeigniter:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

REST is generally less complicated and easier to use, or so they say.

Here's a separate SOAP-supported PHP framework you may be interested in:

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/topics.webservice

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SOAP section](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.html) of [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/).

There are probably some hits on Google for this.